# Mathematical Writing: Can objects in a definition be assigned any name, even though this name is used elsewhere in the text?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, article-writing

Consider the following example:

On page 1 of my paper I write: Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with $1$.

...[some text where I use $R$]...

On page 3 of the paper I write: $\textbf{Definition.}$ Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $U$ be a subset of $R$. The annihilator of $U$ is defined as $\mathrm{Ann}(U):= \{r\in R:rU=0\}.$

Now, consider $r\in R$. <- Would it be clear that $R$ is the finite ring from page 1, which I have used so far, or did the $\textbf{Definition}$ "overwrite" the meaning of $R$?

Is it instead preferable to give the commutative ring in the definition a different name, such as $R'$ for example?

P.S. What are common letters for writing rings apart from $R$ and $S$?

Comment: I think you should give a complete example of what you have in mind.

Comment: I added some more details. Is it better now or still unclear?

Comment: I think it's unclear as written. But I think it would be ok if you put the definition first, and then afterwards said something like: "Now suppose that $R$ is a finite commutative ring with $1$, and let $r \in R$."

Comment: It doesn't make sense for me to put the definition first because I'm introducing the main question and other concepts using $R$ as defined in the beginning. I will edit it again, hopefully this will make it clearer.

Comment: Regarding your question "would it be clear, that..." no, it wouldn't. *After* your definition, $R$ is expected to be a commutative ring with $1$ as in your definition, not necessarily finite.

Comment: @Zest Thank you. My question basically was whether the names in definitions are "closed off" from the rest of the text but according to your answer this is not the case. Hence, I will presumably give the ring in the definition a different name then to avoid confusion.